# How to disable notifications from WatchOS target to remove ITMS-90078 warning?

Tags: xcode, notifications, watchos

I selected include notification scene when creating a watchOS target app. After finishing development I did not use the notification scenes and deleted:

- the related interface controllers from the watch storyboard
- the related notification controller from the extensions
- the .apns file

After upload I received the following warning information:

ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment' entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the 'aps-environment' entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, ...

I use automatically managed signing and an Xcode managed provisioning file.

I have not found other code or settings in the Xcode settings related to notification.

After searching for a while I need some help to eliminate all notification related settings and code from my app to resolve the warning leading to rejection. Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you include / leave push notifications in the extension's Singing & Capabilities section?

Comment: No, I didn't. I use the 'automatically manage signing option'.